# How to report bug in Visual Studio C++ 2010 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense, visual-c++-2010

I have a program (trimmed way down) that compiles and runs as I think it should, yet in the code window an asterisk (operator*) has a red squiggle under it and the mouse-over caption says, 'Error, no operator * matches these operands.' I guess the squiggly line neglected to tell the compiler. The same thing happens if I change operator* to a function named "dot".

If there are few enough hoops to jump through, I would like to report it to MS. But first, tell me if the compiler and I are wrong, and the squiggle is right.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
//#include "fp_vectors.h"
// Header file =================
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>

namespace dj {

    // Dot-product of two real-valued vectors
    template <typename FirstType, typename SecondType> 
    auto operator*(const FirstType &a, const SecondType &b) -> decltype(a[0]*b[0]){
       std::remove_const<decltype(a[0]*b[0])>::type ret = 0.0;
       const int sz = std::min(a.size(),b.size());
       for(int i=0;i<sz;++i) {
           ret += a[i]*b[i];
       }
       return ret;
    }


} // namespace dj

// End header file ================


using namespace std;
typedef vector<float> fvec;
typedef vector<double> dvec;

using namespace dj;

int main()
{
    const size_t sz = 3;
    fvec fv(sz);
    dvec dv(sz);
    for(size_t i=0; i<sz; ++i) {
        fv[i] = -.89f*(i-1.0f);
        dv[i] = 1.6*(i-2.2);
    }
    double ret = dv*fv; // Earns a red squiggly
    cout << ret << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bugs in Visual Studio may be reported on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

However, I took a brief look at your code, and there are no squiggles in Visual Studio 2012.  So, if there was a bug here, it looks like it's been fixed.

Comment: I will just wait for VC++ 2012 then, assuming there is an Express version. No need to learn how to report bugs in VC++ 2010, because it appears they have a new tool for reporting bugs in VC++ 2012 that reduces the hoop-count.

Comment: Microsoft Connect has been around for a while, I think since the Visual Studio 2005 timeframe.  There will be several Express versions:  one for Windows 8 app development, another for desktop app development.

Comment: Will there be an Express version for plain old XP/Vista/Win7? I poked my head into Microsoft Connect. There is at least a bit of a learning curve for VC++ 2010, but the main page is hawking a program that is supposed to make reporting bugs easier for VC++ 2012. I can wait. There is supposed to be some kind of release tomorrow (Aug 15, 2012). We'll see what's in that. Are you an MS employee? Beta tester?

Comment: I work on the Visual C++ team at Microsoft.  Yes, the [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/06/08/visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows-desktop.aspx) will support plain old C++ development for Windows XP, Vista, and 7.  Tomorrow (Aug. 15), Visual Studio 2012 will be available to MSDN subscribers.  I don't know when it will be available generally.  In the meantime, the Release Candidate can be downloaded [from MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads).

Comment: Okay, I am going to mark this answered. I kind of envy you. I wrote two compilers, back in the day (both Pascal, regrettably). Fun projects, they were. I retired a few years ago, and I miss it. So I am cleaning up and modernizing some libraries that I wrote. Will probably donate them to the public domain, or put it under some kind of shareware license and beg for donations. :-) Thanks much.

Comment: Oh, one parting shot... @james I sure hope VC++ 2012 has the option to retain the look and feel of VC++ 2010. I am not a Ludite, just a Lazy Person.